# How to count number of records present in a date range between a fixed time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get the number of records present in my [RecordsTable] for the last 3 months. 
However the catch is I need the records which are processed between 10PM and 2AM.

For example --

```
07/01/2015 10PM -- 07/02/2015 2AM 
07/02/2015 10PM -- 07/03/2015 2AM
07/03/2015 10PM -- 07/04/2015 2AM
```

The below SQL gives me the records present on any particular day starting from May,2015.

But I am not able to get the timing(10PM-2AM of next day) embedded in the SQL and need some help.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), RecordDate, 101),count(RecordID)
FROM [RecordsTable](NOLOCK)
WHERE RecordDate > '2015-05-01'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), RecordDate, 101)
```

Comment: Is the date & time in one column or do you have one column for each?

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL Supports both Date and Time datatypes.  You can break up your where statement to reflect both date and time conditions separately.

```
SELECT COUNT(Records)
FROM TABLE
WHERE CONVERT(Date,DateCol) BETWEEN 'MM/DD/YYYY' AND 'MM/DD/YYYY'
AND CONVERT(Time,DateCol) BETWEEN 'HH:MM:SS' AND 'HH:MM:SS'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM RecordsTable
WHERE RecordDate > '2015-05-01'
 AND NOT DATEPART(hour, RecordDate) BETWEEN 2 AND 21
```

I assume RecordDate is a datetime or datetime2 column. `between 2 and 21` will return rows where the hour for RecordDate is between 2am and 9pm, inclusive. `NOT between 2 and 21` will return the reverse, giving you data for 10pm, 11pm, 12pm, and 1am. This does not include any time between 2:00am and 2:59am. If you need to include events that occurred precisely at but not after 2:00am, things get a bit tricker, but similar code based on `not between` would apply.

Comment: You think using NOT instead of two ANDs is clearer code or do you have experience this code is faster.

Comment: It is clearer because the single clause defines a span of time. Then there's a false argument: Including `or` clauses `(< 2am, > 10pm)` can result in the query optimizer producing sub-optimal plans, so having a single clause would make it faster... except that the query engine probably (I don't know for sure) converts `between` clauses into two `or` clauses. Thus, nice story, but probably not true.

Answer (score 0):

To get records in the last 3 months you can use two ways -- one by month looks like this

```
WHERE MONTH(colname) >= MONTH(GETDATE()) -3
```

This will get you inclusive months but not partial months.  To get partial months is a bit more tricky because you could mean (for example for today) the 9th day of 3 months ago or you could mean 90 days ago.  In the first case this works

```
WHERE colname >= dateadd(month,-3, getdate())
```

and for 90 days ago

```
WHERE colname >= dateadd(day,-90, getdate())
```

To get between 10PM and 2AM use this

```
WHERE datepart(hour,colname) >= 22 OR datepart(hour,colname) <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEPART

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Table1
WHERE RecordDate > '2015-05-01'
   AND (DATEPART(HOUR, RecordDate) <= 2 OR DATEPART(HOUR, RecordDate) >= 22)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tablename where created_at>='2015-03-17 07:15:10' and created_at<='2015-07-09 02:23:50';
```

You can even use between

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tablename where created_at between '2015-03-17 07:15:10' and '2015-07-09 02:26:50';
```

You can use curdate() to get today's date

Comment: You can format your code by selecting it and then using Ctrl K, or wrapping it in tildes `

Comment: I don't understand why you used the timestamps you did.